# Dedicating a paper

Tags: publications

May I dedicate a paper to two persons in different ages on the occasion of their birthdays? For instance, "dedicated to John on his 70th birthday, and to Steve on his 60th birthday." I appreciate it if you could help me with finding a proper sentence.

Comment: Dedications are an exception in scientific papers. Most often, it's done if a prominent researcher has passed away.

Comment: You're asking two things here: (1) can you have a dedication in your paper? (2) How to formulate the dedication you have in mind? Please narrow this down to just one plain question.

Answer (score 1):

> May I dedicate a paper to two persons in different ages on the occasion of their birthdays?

Yes

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like

"Dedicated to John and Steve who celebrate their 60th and 70th birthday."
?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the feasibility with the journal. Most of them don't like it unless the people to whom you would dedicate the work are well reputed at least in the area covered by the journal or unless the entire issue is dedicated.

Edit: the comments below the answer weren't visible *to me* at the time I wrote this. Otherwise I wouldn't have answered but just up voted them. Indeed, normally dedications are "to the memory". Dedications to very prominent researchers when they retire or get indeed old are even more rare.